# React-Native Webview html file doesn't show when offline

Tags: android, html, react-native, webview, offline

I'm creating an app using React-Native. I'm using Webview in order to display a local html file in the app. This works perfectly when the phone has internet connection, but otherwise nothing is shown. Is it possible to have Webview display a local HTML file without internet connection?

Webview code:

```
      WebView
        source={{ uri: 'file:///android_asset/test.html' }}
      />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try -

```
const debugSource = require('../assets/test.html'); // required for bundling
const releaseSourcePrefix = Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'file:///android_asset' : './assets';
const releaseSource = { uri: `${releaseSourcePrefix}/assets/index.html` };
const webViewSource = Image.resolveAssetSource(global.__DEV__ ? debugSource : releaseSource);
<WebView
scalesPageToFit={false}
source={webViewSource}
originWhitelist={["*"]}
style={{ flex: 1, }}
/>
```

Make sure you start with printing Text in HTML first to make sure there is no issue in the HTML file. It will help you to debug faster